# get random number between 400 and 480 in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am confused about `Math.Random()` in javascript in know that this function will return a number between `0` and `1`

i am trying to return a number between 400 and 500 and what i did is this :

```
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 100);
```

but this code may return a value of `100` or `200` 
what is the best practice to create a number where the minimum is `n0` and maximum is `n1`

Comment: Your should take a look at this question : 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Comment: is it 500 or 480? your question is contradicting

Comment: MDN has [example functions that do what you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Using_Math.random()).

Comment: Math.floor((Math.random() * (80 + 1)) + 400)

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * (80 +1)) + 400);
```

`Math.random() * 80` will yield a number between 0 and 80, then just add 400 to it

Comment: if he wants to include 480 then your answer must be 

Math.floor((Math.random() * (80 + 1)) + 400);

Comment: @M22 you're right - thanks for pointing it out